# Unpivoting a Power BI table to reduce columns to only measures

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a query against my data source that returns a dimension (eg, team name), and several the measures (eg, wins, losses) that are tied to a cross against the same dimension. For example:

```
+===========+===============+===============+===============+===============+===========+===========+
|           | Cardinals - W | Cardinals - L | Blue Jays - W | Blue Jays - L | Hawks - W | Hawks - L |
+===========+===============+===============+===============+===============+===========+===========+
| Cardinals | x             | x             | 5             | 10            | 1         | 2         |
+-----------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+-----------+-----------+
| Blue Jays | 10            | 5             | x             | x             | 8         | 4         |
+-----------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+-----------+-----------+
| Hawks     | 2             | 1             | 4             | 8             | x         | x         |
+===========+===============+===============+===============+===============+===========+===========+
```

What I'd like to do is to have this unpivoted to give me 'A' and 'B' columns and non-team-specific 'W' and 'L' columns. For example:

```
+===========+===========+====+====+
| Team A    | Team B    | W  | L  |
+===========+===========+====+====+
| Blue Jays | Cardinals | 10 | 5  |
+-----------+-----------+----+----+
| Blue Jays | Hawks     | 8  | 4  |
+-----------+-----------+----+----+
| Cardinals | Blue Jays | 5  | 10 |
+-----------+-----------+----+----+
| Cardinals | Hawks     | 1  | 2  |
+-----------+-----------+----+----+
| Hawks     | Blue Jays | 4  | 8  |
+-----------+-----------+----+----+
| Hawks     | Cardinals | 2  | 1  |
+===========+===========+====+====+
```

(Because my use case is actually a little different, I'd actually like to have rows for `{Team A=Blue Jays, Team B=Blue Jays, W=x, L=x}` as well).

If I do an Unpivot in the query editor, I end up getting

```
+===========+===============+=======+
|           | Attribute     | Value |
+===========+===============+=======+
| Cardinals | Cardinals - W | x     |
+-----------+---------------+-------+
| Cardinals | Cardinals - L | x     |
+-----------+---------------+-------+
| Cardinals | Blue Jays - W | 5     |
+-----------+---------------+-------+
| Cardinals | Blue Jays - L | 10    |
+-----------+---------------+-------+
| Cardinals | Hawks - W     | 1     |
+-----------+---------------+-------+
| Cardinals | Hawks - L     | 2     |
+-----------+---------------+-------+
| Blue Jays | Cardinals - W | 10    |
+-----------+---------------+-------+
| Blue Jays | Cardinals - L | 5     |
+-----------+---------------+-------+
| Blue Jays | Blue Jays - W | x     |
+-----------+---------------+-------+
| (more rows removed for brevity)   |
+===========+===============+=======+
```

Is there any reasonable way to implement a pivot in this way across my dataset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to Marc's answer, but with a few less steps.

Starting with the unpivoted data.

[image: Start]

Select the Attribute column and select Split Column -> By Delimiter. PowerBI is usually smart enough to autodetect the delimiter, but you can edit it in the dialog if necessary.

[image: Split]

[image: Split config]

[image: Split results]

Then select the Attribute.2 column and select Pivot Column. Change the Values Column to be Value and under the advanced options, change the Aggregate Value Function to Don't Aggregate.

[image: Pivot]

And there you go.

[image: Results]

Comment: I agree Joe, this is more streamlined and, therefore, better.

Answer (score 1):

To get to this:

[image: ![enter image description here]

I started with this as Table1 in the Query Editor:

[image]

Then I selected Column1 and Unpivoted Other Columns:

[image]

...which yielded this:

[image]

Then I added two new columns: one with the W or L extracted from the Attribute column and one with only the team name extracted from the Attribute column. I used `Text.End` and `Text.Start` for those extractions:

[image]

Then I selected the Custom column and pivoted on it, with the Value column selected for the associated values:

[image]

[image]

...which yielded this:

[image]

Then I removed the Attribute column.
Then I selected the W column and Filled Up.
Then I selected the L column and Filled Down.
Then I selected the W column and Filtered out the x's.
Then I right-clicked on the left top corner of the table and selected Remove Duplicates.
Lastly, I renamed the Column1 and Custom.1 columns to Team A and Team B.

Here's my query code:

```
let
Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Cardinals - W", type any}, {"Cardinals - L", type any}, {"Blue Jays - W", type any}, {"Blue Jays - L", type any}, {"Hawks - W", type any}, {"Hawks - L", type any}}),
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Column1"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", "Custom", each Text.End([Attribute],1)),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom.1", each Text.Start([Attribute], Text.Length([Attribute])-4)),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Added Custom1", List.Distinct(#"Added Custom1"[Custom]), "Custom", "Value"),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Pivoted Column",{"Attribute"}),
#"Filled Up" = Table.FillUp(#"Removed Columns",{"W"}),
#"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Filled Up",{"L"}),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filled Down", each ([W] <> "x")),
#"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Filtered Rows"),
#"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Duplicates",{{"Column1", "Team A"}, {"Custom.1", "Team B"}})
in
#"Renamed Columns"
```

I hope this helps.